# Linq2Sql: query optimisation

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query:

1. Get list of required team ids from DB:

   ```
           IList<int> teamIds =
               (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                where sector.Type=typeValue
                group sector by sector.TeamId into teamSectors
                select teamSectors.Key
               ).ToList();
   ```
2. Using this list fetch all sectors for required teams:

   ```
   IList<InfrStadSector> sectorsForAllTeams = (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                            where teamIds.Contains(sector.TeamId)
                            select sector
                           ).ToList();
   ```
3. Create list of Stadiums based on sectors:

   ```
   IList<InftStadium> stadiums = new List<InfrStadium>();
   foreach(int teamId in teamIds)
   {
       IList<InfrStadSector> teamSectors = 
           sectorsForAllTeams.Where(sect=>sect.TeamId==teamIds).ToList();
       stadiums.Add(new InfrStadium(teamId, teamSectors);
   }
   ```

My concern here is that for collection received from DB I need to apply Where/ToList on the client side once per each team

Is there any way to optimize that?

Thanks.

P.S. Potentially, I could sort items on server (using index), then sort teamIds and work with sectors collection without really 'querying' collection... but probably there is a better way to optimize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in one step.

```
var stadiums = DbContext.sectors
                        .Where( s => s.Type == typeValue )
                        .ToLookup( s => s.TeamId )
                        .Select( l => new InfrStadium( l.Key, l.ToList() )
                        .ToList();
```

Although, it would be better if you could have the constructor for `InfrStadium` take an `IEnumerable<Sector>` rather than requiring a `List<Sector>`, then you could omit the extra `ToList`.

Comment: If I apply 'ToList()' to  teamSectors, I receive the following error: Queryable method call expected. Got 'teamSectors.ToList()'. Parameter name: info. Attempt to call 'AsQueryable()' is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697982/linq2sql-query-subquery-optimisation

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to do this once they're converted to objects.  I'll update the answer to reflect the one I gave on your other question.

Comment: Yes, I went this way. Though this answer was not actually tested, seems like it should work. Thanks.