# Linq2Sql: query - subquery optimisation

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
            IList<InfrStadium> stadiums =
                (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                 where sector.Type=typeValue
                 select new InfrStadium(sector.TeamId)
                ).ToList();
```

and InfrStadium class constructor:

```
    private InfrStadium(int teamId)
    {
        IList<Sector> teamSectors = (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                                     where sector.TeamId==teamId
                                     select sector)
                                     .ToList<>();
        ... work with data
    }
```

Current implementation perform 1+n queries, where n - number of records fetched the 1st time.

I want to optimize that.

And another one I would love to do using 'group' operator in way like this:

```
            IList<InfrStadium> stadiums =
                (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                 group sector by sector.TeamId into team_sectors
                 select new InfrStadium(team_sectors.Key, team_sectors)
                ).ToList();
```

with appropriate constructor:

```
    private InfrStadium(int iTeamId, IEnumerable<InfrStadiumSector> eSectors)
    {
        IList<Sector> teamSectors = eSectors.ToList();

        ... work with data
    }
```

But attempt to launch query causes the following error:

> Expression of type 'System.Int32'
>   cannot be used for constructor
>   parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[InfrStadiumSector]'

**Question 1:**

Could you please explain, what is wrong here, I don't understand why 'team_sectors' is applied as 'System.Int32'?

I've tried to change query a little (replace IEnumerable with IQueryeable):

```
            IList<InfrStadium> stadiums =
                (from sector in DbContext.sectors
                 group sector by sector.TeamId into team_sectors
                 select new InfrStadium(team_sectors.Key, team_sectors.AsQueryable())
                ).ToList();
```

with appropriate constructor:

```
    private InfrStadium(int iTeamId, IQueryeable<InfrStadiumSector> eSectors)
    {
        IList<Sector> teamSectors = eSectors.ToList();

        ... work with data
    }
```

In this case I've received another but similar error:

> Expression of type 'System.Int32'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[InfrStadiumSector]'
>   of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[InfrStadiumSector]
>   AsQueryableInfrStadiumSector'

**Question 2:**

Actually, the same question: can't understand at all what is going on here...

P.S. 
I have another to optimize query idea (describe here: [Linq2Sql: query optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697954/linq2sql-query-optimisation)) but I would love to find a solution with 1 request to DB).

Comment: I implemented your above code and didn't get the error that you mention. I had to fix a couple of syntax errors so I suspect that you've not copied your code across correctly. Can you tell me why you are doing work inside your constructor? That's bad practice. I think David B's answer is a good one.

Comment: Probably the reason of problem on my side is that for accessing DB I use to actually linq2sql, but a BLToolkit framework that provides access to IQueryable interface. Will try to talk to the framework owner.

Comment: Enigmativity, I do stuff in constructor because I want to have my object fully initialized after construction. Could you tell why doing work inside constructor is a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pull the data locally and put it into a structure that meets your needs.

```
ILookup<int, InfrStadiumSector> sectorLookup =
(
  from sector in DbContext.sectors
  where sector.Type == typeValue
  select sector
).ToLookup(sector => sector.TeamId);
```

Then project each grouping in that lookup into an instance of InfrStadium (without going back to the database)...

```
IList<InfrStadium> stadiums = sectorLookup
  .Select(x => new InfrStadium(x.Key, x))
  .ToList();
```

And that projection uses this constructor.

```
private InfrStadium(int iTeamId, IEnumerable<InfrStadiumSector> eSectors)
```

Comment: In my original post I didn't mentioned, that I would like also order data by aggregated expression, something like this: orderby team_sectors.Sum(ts=>ts.Size) descending. Therefore with current apporoach I will need to do that on client side. Don't think it really make big difference in performance tough.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure what's going on without a little experimentation.  Are you sure of the order of your parameters in the constructor?  If so, then it might be a problem translating the expression.  You might want to try materializing the query before you attempt to construct the `InfrStadium` objects.  I'll rewrite using extension methods as I think it will be easier to read.

```
var stadiums = DbContext.sectors
                        .ToLookup( s => s.TeamId )
                        .Select( g => new InfrStadium( g.Key, g ) )
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Close but... if grouping is done in the database, he'll be n+1 queries fetching the contents of each group from the database due to the difference between sql's "key and aggregates" grouping result and linq's "hierarchical" grouping result.

Comment: @David - ah, I hadn't thought of that.  Typically I use grouping with aggregates into an anonymous object. I think I need to move the ToList() up one in the chain.

Comment: @David - on second, thought, yours is better, but I like it all chained together.